# How to hide a button when another button is visible to the user in the viewport

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can I hide button B as soon as button A is visible to the user on the screen as the user scrolls. How can I then UN-HIDE button B when A is no longer visible to the user scrolling on the screen? I do not want both buttons to be visible to the user at the same time.

Below is the breakdown of what I have so far.

For an online store I have a cart page that has a **Go To Checkout** button that is visible in the middle of the page when the user scrolls to that part of the page. That button is the following as seen in the code below, this is button A.

```
<div id="horizontalCheckoutBottomPageButtonA"> <div class="cart-section"> <button id="CheckOutA" class="button button--regular" type="submit" name="checkout"  form="cart">Go To Check Out></button>
```

Then I have another button that is actually sticky on the page, button B. This button also takes the user to checkout but it is sticky on the page and follows the user when he scrolls. The button is as follows:

```
<div id="horizontalCheckoutBottomPageButtonB" <div class="container--large container--vertical-space"> <button id="CheckOutB" class="button button--regular button--outline sticky-buttonzzz" type="submit" name="checkout" form="cart">Check Out ></button</div</div>
```

I have tried the following code that just logs in the console for now on whether A is visible or not. It seems like as long as A exists its always logging that its visible even when it's not visible on the screen to the user since he has scrolled past it. I need it to follow the logic I require which is:

1.How can I hide button B as soon as button A is visible to the user on the screen as the user scrolls.

2.How can I then UN-HIDE button B when A is no longer visible to the user scrolling on the screen?

Please see JS code below. Its always just logging "The ButtonA is visible in the viewport", which means that when I am ready to start adding the logic to HIDE the button, its always going to remain visible. How can I fix this and get the 2 results I need?

```
<script>
function isInViewport(el) {
const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
return (
    rect.top >= 0 &&
    rect.left >= 0 &&
    rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
    rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)

);
}

const CheckOutA = 
document.querySelector('#CheckOutA');
const message = document.querySelector('#message');

document.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
const messageText = isInViewport(CheckOutA) ?
    'The ButtonA is visible in the viewport' :
    'The ButtonA is not visible in the viewport';

message.textContent = messageText;

}, {
passive: true
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimum identifiable example so that we can replicate as what is current behaviour and work on it?

Comment: You need an intersection observer.

Answer (score 0):

Most of your code looks fine. Here is a running example. I use the disabled property on the button to show and hide it.

If this is not working in your use case, maybe you can share some more of your code or explain what the difference between this example an your code.

```js
function isInViewport(el) {
  const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
    rect.top >= 0 &&
    rect.left >= 0 &&
    rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
    rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
  );
}

const CheckOutA = document.querySelector('#CheckOutA');
const CheckOutB = document.querySelector('#CheckOutB');
const message = document.querySelector('#message');

document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let inViewport = isInViewport(CheckOutA);
  const messageText = inViewport ?
    'The ButtonA is visible in the viewport' :
    'The ButtonA is not visible in the viewport';

  message.textContent = messageText;
  CheckOutB.disabled = inViewport;
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  height: 200vh;
  position: relative;
}

#CheckOutB:disabled {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#horizontalCheckoutBottomPageButtonB {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid green 2px;
}

#horizontalCheckoutBottomPageButtonA {
  margin-top: 140vh;
  border: solid blue 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="horizontalCheckoutBottomPageButtonB">
  <div class="container--large container--vertical-space">
    <button id="CheckOutB" class="button button--regular button--outline sticky-buttonzzz" type="submit" name="checkout" form="cart">Check Out &gt;</button><span id="message"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="horizontalCheckoutBottomPageButtonA">
  <div class="cart-section">
    <button id="CheckOutA" class="button button--regular" type="submit" name="checkout" form="cart">Go To Check Out &gt;</button>
  </div>
</div>
```